# Can these two timpani play C-G as well as low E-flat?

Tags: timpani

I'm working on a piece that needs to use the same instrumentation as a classical-period piece.  In the piece, the timpani uses exclusively this G and C.

[image]

For my work, I desperately want to use a low E-flat in the timpani part (a major third below the G shown above).  It seems reasonable to me that the percussionist could use a 32" and a 29" timpani, which would give me my low E-flat and Mozart his C and G.  They could also use a 32" and a 26", right?  Is there any reason, other than space in the venue, hassle in moving a larger timpani, or availability, why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Why do you want to play a job for 3 timpani to be played on 2?

Comment: Because there is only space in the venue for 2

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a few range charts, a 32” timpani would give you the necessary range for both an Eb below the staff and the G on the bottom line. The C can be played on a 29” or a 26”. You might even be able to squeeze an Eb out of a 29” since their range ends at F, just a step above but it might sound a little flabby. I have played in many pops and musical theater orchestras where the player would re-tune the timpani several times during a performance. The only issue I can see is if they will have enough time to make the tuning change from G to Eb or vice versa.